# What is the Best Way To show UITextField with only a bottom border?

Tags: user-interface, ios7, uitextfield, uibezierpath, xcode5.1

I would like to have UITextField appear only with a bottom border. See the designer's image below:
[image]

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(150.0, 350.0)];
        [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(250.0, 209.0)];

        CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
        shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
```

I have Tried This but not Getting Appropriate Results.
Any Suggestions ?

Comment: Could you show the result in contrast to what do you want? If you want to underline the text, couldn't you use `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515451/draw-a-line-with-a-calayer