# Is it possible to create a UITextField in iOS 6 with only a bottom border?

Tags: ios, ios6, uitextfield

I want to customize a `UITextField` in `iOS 6` which will look like a transparent text field with only a bottom border.I have found one image in stackoverflow earlier,but as I don't have 10 reputation I can't post a image,but I am posting the link below.

[Text field with bottom border only in ios6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25976119/what-is-the-best-way-to-show-uitextfield-with-only-a-bottom-border)

Comment: Why are you trying to support iOS 6? iOS 9 will be out in a few months.

Comment: I am having training in iOS app development but we student here don't have MAC Book personally at home,so we do use Mountain Lion OS in VMWare and that doesn't support XCODE 5,that's why friend.

@rmaddy

Comment: That's a shame because you are learning on outdated tools using outdated APIs. A lot has changed. That version can't be used to send apps to Apple.

Comment: We will be using XCODE that supports ios7 and beyond in the offices where we will be be working in near future,here we are just getting familier with Objective C and IOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this:

1. Create a seperatorView and add it subview to UITextfield with y axis as the height of textfield.

   ```
   UITextfield *namefield = [[UITextfield alloc] initwithframe:CGRectMake(20,40,70,40)  ];
   UIView *seperator=[UIView new];
   seperator.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
   seperator.frame =CGRectMake(namefield.frame.origin.x, namefield frame.origin.y+namefield.frame.size.height-1, namefield.frame.size.width,1);
   [namefield addSubView:seperator];
   ```
2. By using the CoreAnimation Class

   ```
   CALayer *bottomBorder = [CALayer layer];   
   CGFloat borderWidth = 1;
   bottomBorder.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor; 
   bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, textField.frame.size.height - borderWidth, textField.frame.size.width, textField.frame.size.height);   
   bottomBorder.borderWidth = borderWidth;  
   [textField.layer addSublayer:border];
   textField.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
   ```
3. By creating a custom class for UITextField and overriding drawRect method.
4. Using a image and adding as a backgroundColor to UITextfield.

Comment: Thanks mate...the 2nd one worked for me but I did have to increase the borderwidth to 8.0f,else it was not been able to see.

@Arun Gupta