# Animate 3 lines into arrow in iOS for a uibutton

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, cgaffinetransform

Does anyone know how to animate 3 parallel lines to a right arrow as happens in navigation menu bar to open up a side menu by applying CGAfflineRotation to 3 views .

I really need help on these as so that at-least I can get an idea to start it.

This is what it will be look like some how tried to draw it:-

```
_______                  
_______                        \
_______         to   ___________\
                                /
                               /
```

Any idea or suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, you should use `CGAffineRotation`. I'm giving simple example of what you want, everything should be ofc packed into proper methods, views should be with some basic `autolayouts`/`layoutFrames` etc. I'm just posting possible solution for rotation, quickly written in `viewDidAppear`, what should be changed.

Another option is to use eg `firstView.layer.anchorPoint` and set it to proper position.

```
#define degreesToRadians(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // let's create these 3 views as a lines
    UIView *firstView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 1)];
    [firstView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:firstView];
    UIView *secondView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 53, 50, 1)];
    [secondView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:secondView];
    UIView *thirdView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 56, 50, 1)];
    [thirdView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:thirdView];

    // now we can perform rotation, mind the degree and offsets in transform.
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(24, 1);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, degreesToRadians(45));
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -24, 1);
        firstView.transform = transform;

        transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(24, -1);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, degreesToRadians(-45));
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -24, -1);
        thirdView.transform = transform;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Vive. I will try your approach too.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to do such animation with CALayer Animation instead of UIView Animation. You need to add three sub layers: top_line, middle_line, and bottom_line. Then draw the line on each layer and the right position ([Hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515451/draw-a-line-with-a-calayer): use `CAShapeLayer` for drawing lines). At last just rotate the top_line and bottom_line layer with a proper angle, you probably need to change the anchor point and layer's position as well. It is quite tricky at the last step, maybe just do some trials with different angle and anchor point values until you find the most proper ones.
When you successfully did such animation, try to do the reverse animation. Then create a Custom UIButton with these two animations embedded in. Congratulations! You have a hamburger button with cool animations which could be reused anywhere!